# Full Calendar: Animate an event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to Animate the event in the calendar I have change color.
So

1. I select my date Alert from the database, I compare dates (date Alert , today)
2. I change color event
3. I Animate event

   ```
   eventRender: function(event, element) { 

   function compareDates() {

   var d = new Date();
   var today = d.format("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");
   <?php 
   mysql_connect("","","");
   mysql_select_db("");
          $requete = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM evenement where id_user=1 ') ;
          while ($ligne=mysql_fetch_array($requete))
          {
           $date=$ligne['dateAlert'];
           $id=$ligne['id_event'];

           ?>

   var dateAlert = '<?php echo $date;?>';
   if(dateAlert == today){
   var id='<?php echo $id;?>';

   alert('alert ID rdv:'+id);

   var rdv=$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
   for (i=0; i<=rdv.length-1; i++) {

   if(rdv[i].id==id){
   rdv[i].backgroundColor='red';
   rdv[i].borderColor='red';

       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', id );

           }

   }
     //where i put this ligne?

    setInterval(function(){ element.fadeOut(900).delay(300).fadeIn(800);
                           },2000);
   }

    <?php }?>

   }
       myvar=setInterval(function(){compareDates()},1000);

   },
   ```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the demo hope this fits into your requirement.

```
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();


        Date.prototype.formatMMDDYYYY = function(){
            return this.getMonth() + 
            "/" +  this.getDate() +
            "/" +  this.getFullYear();
        }

        var todaysDate = new Date();

        var rdv = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    events: [
                        {
                              "title":"Hello World",
                              "start":"Wed, 08 Apr 2013 09:00:00 EST",
                              "end":"Wed, 08 Apr 2013 10:00:00 EST"
                        },
                        {
                              "title":"Good Afternoon",
                              "start":"Wed, 03 Apr 2013 13:00:00 EST",
                              "end":"Wed, 03 Apr 2013 17:00:00 EST"
                        },
                    ],
                    eventRender: function(event, element) {
                        var eventDate = new Date(event.start);
                        if(todaysDate.formatMMDDYYYY() === eventDate.formatMMDDYYYY()) {
                            setInterval(function(){
                                element.fadeOut(900).delay(300).fadeIn(800);
                            },2000);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/rCAnK/3/)

Comment: Thanks for you reply Mahesh Sapkal, but All the events blink!! can I select one specific event?

Comment: so which condition defines that the event should blink or not ??? You can check for the title of the event using event.title. Let's say if you want that Good Afternoon should only blink then check with event.title === 'Good Afternoon'.

Comment: Actually I have an alert if(today== dateAlert) i will change the color to red and blink the event!! So far i could change the color in the previous code but i couldn't make the event blink

Comment: It's look perfect but i couldn't make it!! i've edited my code by the way! i'm still messing something!!

Comment: how can I make it work? still no animation or all the event blink!!

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
    rdv[i].fadeOut(900).delay(300).fadeIn(800);
},2200);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply silentw, i tried your solution but i still have this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fadeOut' of undefined rendezvous.php:512

Comment: use `$(rdv[i])` instead of `rdv[i]`. The element `rdv[i]` isn't a jQuery object.

Comment: I see the error is gone but there is no animation! there is something messing ?

Comment: Maybe if you could post some example on some site for example jsfiddle.net I could give more help on it...